# cw and . does not work as expected in vim on character deletion

Tags: vim, cygwin

If I have the following non-sense text:

```
Hi woman! What is your name? I know what you mean...  
Yeap.  
Yeap. Again :)  
Hi woman! What i s your name? I know what you mean...  
Yeap.  
Yeap. Again :)  
Hi woman! What is your name? I know what you mean...  
Yeap.  
Yeap. Again :)  
Hi woman! What is your name? I know what you mean...  
Yeap.  
Yeap. Again :)
```

and I want to replace all occurences of `woman` with `man` I do:
Go my cursor to the first occurence of `woman` which is on the first line. I press `*` and all occurrences are highlighted.
Then I type `cw` and delete `w` and `o` and press `ESC`.
Then I press `n` and move to the next occurrence.
Then I type `.` and expect that `wo` will be removed. 
But only `w` is deleted. Why?

Comment: `cw` would delete the word `woman` in total. Why not `:%s/woman/man/gc`?

Comment: How are you deleting the `w` and `o`? What keys are you pressing?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman:`del` in insert mode

Comment: Is `Enter` supposed to be `Escape`?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman:Yes.I will correct OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the characters in insert mode, delete them in normal mode. Navigate to `woman` and type `2x` to delete the first two characters.

Or, you can use substitution: `:%s/woman/man/g`.